# Make variable used in any() visible outside

Tags: python

How to print the match string outside of the if statement?

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
for line in file:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        print "s is:",s
```

says:

```
NameError: global name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: This is not a use-case for `any`, just use a loop:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generator, and call for the `next(..)`:

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
for line in file:
    result = next((s for s in strings if s in line),None)
    if result is not None:
        print "s is:",s
```

Here we use `None` in the `next` as a fallback value if no such `s` can be found that matches and check for `None`.

Note that this will match only the *first* of the matches. If there are more, these will not be emited. You can however alter the code by using a `for` loop:

```
for line in file:
    for s in strings:
        if s in line:
            print "s is:",s
```

Answer (score 4):

As the [`any` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) says:

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is
>   empty, return `False`.

And you can not access the intermediate variable used within `any(...)` *(scope of generator expression)* outside the scope of it.

In order to achieve this, you may instead do:

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
existed = None

for line in file:
    for s in strings:
        if s in line:
            existed = s
            break
    if existed:
        print "s is:",s
```

Answer (score 2):

You just can't, the variable is declared only inside the generator.
You'll have to add another for loop for that:

```python
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
for line in file:
    for s in strings:
        if s in line:
            print "s is:",s
```

But you can avoid nesting for loops using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Willem Van Onsem's comments.

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
for line in file:
    result = next((s for s in strings if s in line),None)
    if result is not None:
        print "s is:",result
```